# set up dependencies between 2 separate ADF environments

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to know, in order to set up dependencies between 2 separate ADF environments.
I know this is possible through setting a trigger/web activity.

Is there is any point of failures in the scheduling the inter ADF pipelines? We need to be 100% sure for this solution.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried? if you are facing any error? and explain bit more about question

Comment: `in order to set up dependencies between 2 separate ADF environments..` and then you're not telling in order to what?

Comment: How to schedule dependency between 2 ADFs for Ingestion

Comment: I mentioned we wanted to keep the 2 environments separate. And the dependency will be set up between pipelines of ingestion ADF and another one  for some other purpose ADF

Comment: also two different resource group one scenario

Comment: and another one scenario two different subscription

Comment: Please do not use the tag [azure-pipelines] for questions related to Azure Data Factory pipelines. [azure-pipelines] is for questions related to Microsoft's Azure DevOps pipelines feature.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to set up dependencies:

1. You can trigger an ADF pipeline via web activity thereby linking those 2 ADFs
2. You can generate a file in blob at the end of 1st pipeline and configure event trigger for another pipeline

Comment: My question is little different which i have two different resource group, i have the pipelines, if it is different RG, what is the pros and cons. similarly two different subscription , how to do we handle the pipelines trigger and etc.. if we for that what is the pros and cons.

Comment: both scenario, how do we handle.

Comment: It doesnt matter if those are in 2 diff RGs or 2 diff subscriptions or 2 diff ADFs within the same RG. For all the scenarios , the above either of the logic would remain the same

Comment: @karthikelavan hope this clarified